# Cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment

Tags: c#, multithreading, pdf

So whilst I am getting this error `cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.` and there are other answers, I'm still getting the same problem and perhaps my implementation is the problem:-

I have a main application, lets call it "Core" for now and assume for the sake of argument it has a call out like so:-

`Pdf.Generate.Create(file, savepath);`

`Pdf` is a class library (dll) within the solution and it contains the following code only:-

```
using System.Threading;
using Spire.Pdf;

namespace Pdf
{
    public class Generate
    {
        public static void Create(string urltoconvert, string savepath)
        {
            var doc = new PdfDocument();
            var thread = new Thread(() => doc.LoadFromHTML(urltoconvert, false, true, true));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();
            doc.SaveToFile(savepath);
            doc.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(savepath);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I receive is thrown by `Pdf` on the `LoadFromHTML` call. I have posted on the `Spire.PDF` [boards just-in-case](http://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/single-thread-apartment-t4662.html), but I think this maybe because of how I try to call out to `Create`. I don't understand the error and that is why I have posted - not just looking for an answer, but also some understanding!

Help, as always, is appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about it cannot possibly be answered due to the fact the question was asked due to a programming error. It offers no value to another user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't a multi-threaded problem at all. Sorry everyone. Typically, once I started stepping through it with logging (log4net), which I installed after I posted, I found that the path to the file was wrong. Whilst the error was utterly misleading, the problem was there was no file to read from. I've +1'd those who have take the time to answer.

Comment: You should not be upvoting *incorrect* answers to a question.  It will give future readers the false impression that those answers answer the question, and they'll then be disappointed when they don't.  You should upvote answers that *answer the question* and solve the problem.

Comment: Not the case. An upvote can be used to indicate a helpful answer, not necessarily the correct answer.

Comment: In what way is a completely incorrect, completely inaccurate, answer that encourages extremely bad practices helpful?  Encouraging poor quality answers helps nobody and can be *very* harmful.  When you upvote every answer, including actively harmful answers, it makes good and correct answers indistinguishable, while also encouraging people to continue to post low quality or incorrect answers.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. There is "no" answer to this question. The question itself was because of a mistake on my part and therefore I wanted to thank the contributors who gave their time and knowledge, knowing that I cannot possibly mark their answers as correct.  Based on your logic, why have upvoting at all? The answer for the question is clearly marked.

Comment: Either way, the question itself is unhelpful on this occasion and I have voted to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the same thread instead of delegating the work to another thread and simply waiting for it to complete?

```
public static void Create(string urltoconvert, string savepath)
{
    var doc = new PdfDocument();
    doc.LoadFromHTML(urltoconvert, false, true, true);
    doc.SaveToFile(savepath);
    doc.Close();
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(savepath);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this method exactly the same error. On checking the forums for Spire PDF, it seems the solution is to do as I have done in code above. Alas, that throws the same error.

Comment: Does adding [stathreadattribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to main method helps?

Comment: No, adding the [STAThread] attribute to the public method gives the same error. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should create the PDF document on the same thread which calls LoadFromHTML. The PDF generator may be using a Single apartment COM object internally which is throwing the exception.

Comment: Do you mean `var doc = new PdfDocument();` within the thread?

Comment: Yes, you can try that.

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work either :(  I created a private method which I used as the "thread starter" method, this included the PDF instantiation. No luck, same error. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public static void Create(string urltoconvert, string savepath)
        {
 this.BeginInvoke((System.Threading.ThreadStart)delegate()
            {
            var doc = new PdfDocument();
            var thread = new Thread(() => doc.LoadFromHTML(urltoconvert, false, true, true));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();
            doc.SaveToFile(savepath);
            doc.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(savepath);

 });
        }
```

Comment: First off, this assumes this is a winform app.  You don't know if that's the case.  Next, if it were, and you did do this, then you'd be blocking the UI thread, which shouldn't be done.  There'd also be no point in a new thread if you're just going to block the UI thread anyway.

Comment: The application is a web application. The PDF namespace is a class library within the web solution.